# Show border of an object on mouseover(Fabricjs)

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to show borders of an object on the mouseover. i tried to use 'mouse:over' event of fabric and manually selected the object.

```
canvas.on('mouse:over', function(opts){
    var selectedObj = opts.target;  
    canvas.setActiveObject(opts.target);
});
```

But there is one problem with this approach. I select one object and then try to do some operation by clicking some buttons(outside canvas). On the way of clicking button, if there is some object then that objects get selected.

So any other way to show borders of an object on its mouseover?

Answer (score 0):

this is the trick that i do on my project , to programmatically activate an object and of course to show the borders and controls.

```
            //your object here should be opts.target
            //you set active property to true
              canvas.item(canvas._objects.length-1).set('active',true);
              canvas._activeObject = null;
           //again here you put opts.target
              canvas.setActiveObject(canvas._objects[canvas._objects.length-1]);
           //this helps to refresh
              canvas.renderAll();
```

and on 'mouse:out' event you can as well disable the active object, for the borders to show off.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas.on('mouse:over', function(opts) {
  var selectedObj = opts.target;
  canvas.setActiveObject(opts.target);
canvas.renderAll();
});
```